# When can we use normal coordinates for a "proof"?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, coordinate-systems, covariance

So I'm trying to find the equations of motion of a field in a particular metric. I know what the equations of motion of the field in flat space look like and how they simplify. I think it's always valid to go to normal coordinates, but it just seems suspect to me at the moment although I'm not sure why.
The equation of motion is that of a spin-2 field.

$$\nabla^2S_{\mu\nu}-\nabla^{\rho}\nabla_{\mu}S_{\rho\nu}+\nabla_{\beta}\nabla_{\alpha}S^{\alpha\beta}+\nabla_{\mu}\nabla_{\nu}S-\nabla^{\rho}\nabla_{\nu}S_{\rho\mu}-\nabla^2Sg_{\mu\nu}-m^2(S_{\mu\nu}-g_{\mu\nu}S)=0 .$$

With $S$ being the trace of the field and $m$ its mass. Now, if we got to normal coordinates, we can show by taking the trace of the EoM

$$2\nabla^{\beta}\nabla^{\alpha}S_{\alpha\beta}- 2\nabla^2S=3m^2S.$$

And then by taking the divergence of the EoM we can show S=0.
Then, using these two conditions, the EoM simplifies drastically down to a K-G style equation

$(\nabla^2-m^2)S_{\mu\nu}=0$

This is obviously a lot nicer, and it's also true in flat space for a spin-2 field. I don't know why I wouldn't be allowed to just change to N.C to get down to this but I'm just not confident in the result.

ETA: just to clear things up, I know I can take the trace in any coordinate system. I'm not going to N.C here so that I can take the trace, I'm going to N.C so that I can commute the derivatives

Comment: What is stopping you from from taking the the trace without going to normal coordinates?

Comment: The only question that matters here is: do you lose generality when choosing a coordinate system?
In your case, it only serves in taking the trace of the EoM. If you know if the trace is dependent on the coordinate system, then you know the answer of whether you can use this special set of coordinates.
Hint: tracing is not dependent on the coordinate system

Comment: If $S_{\mu\nu}$ is a spin-2 field isn't its trace zero by definition? (The trace would be an additional spin-0 scalar.)

Comment: @mment I can take the trace without going to normal coordinates, but I wouldn't get the same result. Going to N.C lets me commute the derivatives so that I get the nice result. As for it being traceless by definition, I thought this was true too, but apparently one needs the trace in the action otherwise we get "ghost" particles

Comment: @Naptzer I'm not sure I follow what you're saying. I change coordinates not so I can take the trace but so that I can commute the derivatives

Comment: If covariant derivatives do not commute in one set of coordinates, they better not be commuting in another. And if you introduce interaction of FP field with background spacetime just by replacing flat space EOMs with covariant derivatives, you *will* get ghosts, see [hep-th/9910188](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9910188).

Comment: @A.V.S. in N.C. covariant derivatives commute at the origin since the Riemann tensor there is 0... no? But thanks for the answer as to whether the EoM is valid this way, although I'm still unsure as to why it's not

Comment: No, the Riemann tensor is not zero in normal coordinates, since it contains second derivatives of the metric, and only first derivatives of the metric are set to zero in normal coordinates.

Comment: Christoffel symbols are zero at origin in NC, but not its derivatives. So evaluating $∇_β∇_α T_{…}$ at origin of NC would still contain derivatives of Christoffel symbols.

Comment: ahh thank you, it was such a simple answer and such a stupid overlook on my part!